# What is the joint probabilities p(L, R), p(G, L), and the probabilities p(L), p(G)

Tags: probability

A set of 30 objects has two attributes. The first is size and it can be L (large) or S (small). The second is colour and it can be R (red), Y(yellow) or G (green). The table below shows the number of objects for each case:

[image]

What is the joint probabilities p(L, R), p(G, L), and the probabilities p(L), p(G)

My attempt:

p(L, R), p(G, L) = 1/30 * 12/30 = 1/75

p(L), p(G) = 18/30 * 17/30 = 17/50

Comment: This is not clear.  What does $P(L,R),P(G,L)$ mean?

Comment: That is how the question is worded on this practice paper so I'm not sure myself

Comment: Well, what do you think it means?  It really isn't possible for us to guess at what you intend here.  If your paper is unclear, ask for clarification from whomever wrote it.

Comment: I thought what it meant was that if the person selects two objects from the bag what is the probability of picking an object that is large and red and then picking an object that is green and large

Comment: I guess I'll just have to check with whoever wrote it

Comment: There's nothing in that notation that suggests that reading.  I'd have thought that $P(G,L)$ just meant the joint probability that an object be $G$ and $L$.